# Combine Two iEnumerable Objects with ID

Tags: linq, object, merge

It must be that time of year.  Totally having a brain fart.
I have two basic iEnumerable objects.  Each object has two fields.  In the first object I have a field with an ID and then total.
Id  Total
1    23
2    16
3    59
...

In the other object it has a ID field and then Fruit Name
ID  Fruit
1   Apple
2   Orange
3.  Pear

I need to combine these into a new table by the ID so I get a new object with the fields
ID  Total  Fruit
1    23    Apple
2    16    Orange
3    59    Pear

What's the best way to go about this using LINQ?

Comment: The term is join. Lookup how to perform a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a join

```
from o in iEobject
join f in Fruit on o.ID equals f.ID
select new {ID = o.ID, Total = o.Total, Fruit = f.Name }
```